# Build fails with error: react-native-navigation:compileReactNative63DebugKotlin

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, build.gradle, react-native-navigation

I am trying to build react native application for android but getting this error `react-native-navigation:compileReactNative63DebugKotlin`. I am not an expert on React Native but here is my configurations. How can I solve this?

- Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "https://github.com/flyingSAP/react-native-blur",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "hermes-engine": "0.10.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-devtools": "^4.24.7",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.4",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^6.4.3",
    "react-native-auth0": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.2.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-eventemitter": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.27.0",
    "react-native-option-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-sha256": "^1.4.7",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-oidc": "^4.0.0-beta1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "shell-quote": "1.7.3"
  },
```

- Build script

```
ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

- Error output

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative63DebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

    at makeError (/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

- Tried updating react native to 0.64.4
- Tried using Kotlin versions 1.6.0 and 1.6.10
- Removed .gradle folder and tried building
- Tried ./gradlew clean
- Updated react-native-navigation to 7.27.0

Comment: try to use this: buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        appCompatVersion = "1.4.2"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"

Comment: @RodrigoDias I tried this but now getting                                                                 
"A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle" I have added "compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion" to android/app/build.gradle as well but it does not work

Comment: i do have this line inside the android/app/build,gradle     compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

Comment: I have that line as well. I am not sure if it is something about kotlin version and react native version incompatibility

Comment: Fixed this with upgrading react-native-navigation package to the right version!